# Jenkins dynamic stages with separate agents

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

### Setup

- Kubernetes v1.27 (EKS)
- Jenkins installed from [helm chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts)
- Jenkins configured from code (CaaC) with [shared libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

### Jenkins shared library configuration

All files are located in `var` directory

`pipelineTemplate.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call() {
  pipeline {
    agent {
      kubernetes {
         yaml kaniko()
      }
     }

    stages {
      stage ('1. Build') {
        steps {
          kanikoBuild()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`kaniko.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(){
agent =  """
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    labels:
      role: agent
    name: jenkins-build
    namespace: jenkins
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: jenkins-agent
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: kaniko-docker
    containers:
    - name: kaniko
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.10.0-debug
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command:
      - /busybox/cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
      - name: kaniko-docker
        mountPath: /kaniko/.docker
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 3
          memory: 5Gi
    restartPolicy: Never
    volumes:
    - name: kaniko-docker
      projected:
        sources:
        - secret:
            name: kaniko-docker
            items:
              - key: .dockerconfigjson
                path: config.json
"""
return agent
}
```

`kanikoBuild.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def generateStage(job) {
  return {
    stage("Build ${job}") {
      sh """
        executor \
        -f `pwd`/Dockerfile-${job} \
        -c `pwd` \
        --cache=true \
        --cache-repo=mydocker/${job} \
        --destination=mydocker/${job}:${env.GIT_COMMIT}
      """
    }
  }
}

def call() {
  container('kaniko') {
    def stagesList = [:]
    def parallelStagesMap = ''
  
    stagesList = [
      "app1",
      "app2"
    ]

    parallelStagesMap = stagesList.collectEntries {["${it}" : generateStage(it)]}
                
    parallelStagesMap.failFast = false
    parallel parallelStagesMap
  }
}
```

### What is working

When I add new item to `stagesList` it create new stage dynamically which is great since I can update only one place and don't need to bother with copy-past code for `kaniko` executor

### What is not working

Since `kaniko` is design to run only single executor in one pod my pipeline is failing since parallel stages are run on the same pod which is `kaniko`. This is also problem since I would like to add different resource allocation for some applications like 5CPU for `app1` and 2CPU for `app2`.

### What I would like to achieve

I would like to run each dynamically generated stage of my pipeline on different executor which means that each application define is `stagesList` should start separate pod with `kaniko` and build the application.

I was trying various things like adding pod definition to `generateStage` function but without any luck.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `podTemplate()` step.

Example :

```
def generateStage(job) {
  return {
    stage("Build ${job}") {
      podTemplate(yaml: kaniko()) {
        node(POD_LABEL) {
          checkout scm
          container('kaniko') {
            sh """
              executor \
              -f `pwd`/Dockerfile-${job} \
              -c `pwd` \
              --cache=true \
              --cache-repo=mydocker/${job} \
              --destination=mydocker/${job}:${env.GIT_COMMIT}
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-using-the-pipeline-step) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion Eric! This works great for me. For further reference under `node(POD_LABEL) {` should also be `container('kaniko') {` since by default it will run on `jnlp` container. The only downside of this is that you need to once again clone app repository but this can be easily done with `git` block.

Comment: @MichałLewndowski I updated my answer, taking into account your remarks. Can you confirm it's OK ?

Comment: With `container` block and `checkout scm` it work like a charm! Once again thanks.